# React Native: calling swift code on button press from js

Tags: ios, swift, reactjs, react-native

I am building a mobile application using react native and I dont need to call native code except for handling payments.
I have written a swift class that takes care of the payments, however, I cant seem to find a way to call a method in the swift class from the js code in react native. Is it possible to do that or do I have to write a separate view in swift and add all other react native views to the main app?
Thanks!